# ArangoDB Fail to Start on AWS EC2 with Docker and Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu, aws-cloudformation, arangodb

I have a setup in which a Java program is used to start the ArangoDB. Following code will start the ArangoDB.

```
  ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(arangodExecFile);
  processBuilder.environment().put("hostaddress", host);          
  arangodbProcess = processBuilder.start();
```

I have also tried using `arangodbProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arangodExecFile, env_hostaddress);`
The program is running inside a Docker container that uses Ubuntu as a base image. The implementation is working fine, and ArangoDB starts without any issues.

When I deploy the same Docker image on an AWS EC2 instance, ArangoDB fails to start with the following error:

```
2023-10-25T10:26:08Z [50] ERROR [874fa] {communication} unable to bind to endpoint 'http+tcp://host_ip:8529': Address not available
2023-10-25T10:26:08Z [50] FATAL [c81f6] {general} failed to bind to endpoint 'http+tcp://host_ip:8529'. Please check whether another instance is already running using this endpoint and review your endpoints configuration.
```

I do not have an ENDPOINTS file. The server.endpoint is properly configured to start the ArangoDB on the AWS instance, using the AWS instance's IP address. I am using the AWS instance IP to bind the server endpoint so that I can access it from a different machine. Making a call to ArangoDB endpoint is done from a different AWS instance to get ArangoDB driver and it should not affect the starting of ArangoDB, it can cause an issue when I try to get the ArangoDB object of the ArangoDB process which is running.

- I confirmed that the port is not being used by any other process
  using  `ss -tulpn`.
- Additionally, I have also added a command to kill    any existing
  ArangoDB processes using  `kill -9 $(ps axf | grep    arangod | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')`.
- I tried adding/removing    the port to security group rules to allow
  traffic on port 8529 and       mapped/unmapped the port in the
  'docker run' command.
- If I access the Docker container running on AWS and start ArangoDB by
  executing the arangod file using `./arangodb` or `sudo ./arangod` the ArangoDB starts
  without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "deploy the same Docker image on an AWS EC2 instance" you mean that you have set up Docker on your EC2 instance, and it serves a Docker host.

Applications running inside a Docker container, by default, don't have access to your host's network. It means that your ArangoDB instance won't see any of your EC2 instance's IP addresses. What it will see is the Docker virtual network with its own IP address.

Docker has the ability to forward packets between the host network and the container's network. To do that, you need to expose the ports that you want forwarded. You can do that by publishing your containers ports to the host by using `docker run --publish 8529:8529` or similar.

Inside your container, you should bind your listening socket to the internal network interface. You can do this by getting your container's hostname from within the container, and, optionally, resolving its IP address (if ArangoDB requires binding by IP). When starting containers, Docker rewrites their `/etc/hosts` so that the container's hostname resolves to its internal address. You won't need to pass the host address from the outside anymore.

Alternatively, you can run your Docker container so that it shares the host's network (by using `docker run --network=host`), but it's less secure and harder to configure (this way, you do need to know the host address to bind your listening socket to).

Comment: Regarding docker run --publish 8529:8529 I have tried this, I have also mentioned this as the third point of my question. If I publish the port using docker run --publish 8529:8529 or -p 8529:8529, the ArangoDB assumes as the process is already running on that port.

Comment: @slow_learner: did you also implement my other suggestion, namely "you should bind your listening socket to the internal network interface"? It's equally important.

Comment: ArangoDB requires binding by IP. I am getting container's hostname from within the container in my code. When you mentioned 'bind your listening socket to the internal network interface' I assume you mean --server.endpoint on which ArangoDB listens should be configured to listen on the host name of the Docker container. I have implemented this.

Comment: @slow_learner: this entry in your post "I am using the AWS instance IP to bind the server endpoint" contradicts what you just said, please make it consistent. Also, could you please explicitly clarify the values of all these variables you are using? I.e. what the value of `host` in your java code is, what `env_hostaddress` is etc. Just do `ip addr` inside your Docker container, `ip addr` inside your EC2 instance etc. Redact your real ip, of course. Thank you!

Comment: I made some additional modifications after posting the initial question. Initially, I was using the AWS EC instance's private IP as the server endpoint for ArangoDB.

Here's my current implementation: 
 
 // getContainerIP() will fetch the Docker container IP of the Docker container running inside the AWS EC2 instance
 String containerIP = getContainerIP();
 ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(arangodExecFile);
 processBuilder.environment().put("hostaddress", containerIP); // sets an environment variable
 arangodbProcess = processBuilder.start();

Comment: Then, in the 'arangod' file, I read the 'hostaddress' set as an environment variable:
 hostaddress=$(env  | grep hostaddress | grep -oe '[^=]*$');
 
 I use the 'hostaddress' to set the endpoint in the 'arangod' file as follows:
 --server.endpoint tcp://$hostaddress:8529 \
 
 I also attempted to hardcode 'hostaddress' in the --server.endpoint tcp://$hostaddress:8529 by accessing the Docker container.

Comment: ArangoDB is starting now. Thank you for your support. @Quassnoi

Comment: @slow_learner: glad that it worked out. If it was my post that solved your problem, could you please mark it as accepted? If it wasn't, could you please post what you did as a separate answer and mark that as accepted as well? Thank you.